# How to call one function app from another locally?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

In Visual Studio, I have created 2 Azure function apps `f1` and `f2`.

I have already change the port for both function apps.

I want to call `f2` from `f1` but I'm getting a `NotFound` error.

- `f1` is using http://localhost:999/demo1
- `f2` is using http://localhost:1212/demo2

Comment: Nope both use different url with port no is also different

Comment: Are they function apps within the same solution or different solutions?

Comment: What type of triggers? Maybe an example of how you've written your functions (primarily interested in the bindings and attributes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried calling `one Function` to `Another Function` within the same project and different project too both works fine.

***Function 1 Example:***

```cs
 [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        try
        {
            //Extract Request Param

            var content = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            QnAMakerQuestion objQnAMakerQuestion = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QnAMakerQuestion>(content);

            //Global Variable for containing message

            dynamic validationMessage;

            // Validate param

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(objQnAMakerQuestion.question))
            {
                validationMessage = new OkObjectResult("Question is required!");
                return (IActionResult)validationMessage;
            }
            //Selialize Request Param
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objQnAMakerQuestion);
            var stringContent = new StringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            // Call Function 2 
            HttpClient newClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage responseFromAnotherFunction = await newClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:7073/api/Function2FromApp2", stringContent);
            dynamic response = "";

            if (responseFromAnotherFunction.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                response = responseFromAnotherFunction.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }

            validationMessage = new OkObjectResult(response);
            return (IActionResult)validationMessage;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            dynamic validationMessage = new OkObjectResult(string.Format("Something went wrong, please try agian! Reason:{0}", ex.Message));
            return (IActionResult)validationMessage;
        }
    }
```

***Function 2 Example:***

```cs
  [FunctionName("Function2FromApp2")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            try
            {
                var content = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
                QnAMakerQuestion objQnAMakerQuestion = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QnAMakerQuestion>(content);

                //Global Variable for containing message

                dynamic validationMessage;

                // Validate param

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(objQnAMakerQuestion.question))
                {
                    validationMessage = new OkObjectResult("Question is required!");
                    return (IActionResult)validationMessage;
                }
                validationMessage = new OkObjectResult(objQnAMakerQuestion);
                return (IActionResult)validationMessage;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                dynamic validationMessage = new OkObjectResult(string.Format("Something went wrong, please try agian! Reason:{0}", ex.Message));
                return (IActionResult)validationMessage;
            }
        }
```

***Class Used:***

```
   public class QnAMakerQuestion
    {
        public string question { get; set; }

    }
```

> **Note:** If you run in same project then you wouldn't encounter any problem. But if you run in different project encounter a issue
>   regarding port. To resolve that in `local.settings.json` file replace
>   below code :

```
"Host": {

    "LocalHttpPort": 7073

  }
```

And `Update Project Properties -> Debug to following`

`host start --port 7073 --pause-on-error` See the screen shot below:

[image]

***Post Man Test:***

I have invoked `Function 1` on PostMan it Invoked `Function 1` as `Function 1` Invoked `Function 2` and Send Response or vice-versa from `function 2` to `function 1`. See the screen shot below:

[image]

Just plug and play, let me know if you have any additional question.